# Replace %20 with space character while saving file iOS

Tags: objective-c, file, save, space

I am now recording audio file and saving to document directory. The given name contain space character. When I save to document directory, space characters are changed to %20. I would like to know how to save properly so that that audio file name contain space character.

```
    NSString *myDBnew = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:recordingAudioName ];
    NSURL *recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myDBnew];
```

**Edited - This is to do audio recording and save to local directory.** 
 
        recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];

Comment: This is how you get the file name, how did you save the file?

Comment: Is the audio file NSData?

Comment: I have updated my question. I use AVAudioRecorder to start recording and save automatically to document directory.

Answer (score 1):

You're using NSURL and spaces are invalid characters in a URL.  That's why it's converted to a %20.

Comment: yes..exactly..how should I allow to have space character? I need to use NSURL to start recording with AVAudioRecorder.

Comment: Since you must use a `NSURL`, you're stuck with the %20 while recording.  After recording, you can use a `NSFileManager` along with `moveItemAtPath` to a different filename.

Comment: @KhantThuLinn What's wrong with having %20 in the filename?  Is that really a problem?

Comment: :D ... %20 doesn't look nice for a file name. Thanks. I am now using the one you suggest. I rename that file.

Answer (score 0):

please use

`-(BOOL)writeToFile:options:error:`
instead of 
`-(BOOL)writeToURL:options:error:`.

`writeToFile` takes a `NSString` as argument (not a `NSURL`). The spaces are preserved this way.

```
NSString *myDBnew = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:recordingAudioName];
NSerror *error;
if (![data writeToFile:myDBnew options:0 error:&error]) {
    // Error handling
}
```

Comment: Why down vote this? This is perfectly correct if you want to save NSData to a local file!

Comment: I am now using AVAudioRecorder and I need to save file name with space. How shall I do? recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];

Comment: I am afraid, you cannot. AVAudioRecorder only accepts URLS. You maybe can work with a temp file (without spaces) and rename it later on?